# How to edit r function to not have repeating values in column

Tags: r

I am trying to change the activity column in the `beaver2 dataset` (prepackaged `dataset` in `R`) into a character vector such that the value `0` is replaced with `idle` and the value `1` is replaced with `active`. This is what I have tried so far but every row within the column is coming out as `active` for some reason.

```
rownames1 <- rownames(beaver2)
for(i in 1:length(rownames1)){
  if(rownames1[i] == "0")
    beaver2$activ[i] = 'idle'
  else beaver2$activ[i] = 'active'
}
print(beaver2)
```

Comment: `beaver2$activ <- ifelse(beaver2$activ == 0, 'Idle', 'active')` doesn't work for you?

Comment: one of the requirements was to not use ifelse() and tidyverse, so i made a conditional loop similar to the if else statement instead. the ifelse() you have suggested works perfectly though!

Answer (score 1):

Since `activ` column contains 1/0 value you can use that as an index to subset and directly do :

```
beaver2$newcol <- c('idle', 'active')[beaver2$activ + 1]
```

---

However, I think you have to use `for` loop here in which case you can do :

```
beaver2$newcol <- NA

for(i in seq_len(nrow(beaver2))){
  if(beaver2$activ[i] == 0)
    beaver2$newcol[i] = 'idle'
  else beaver2$newcol[i] = 'active'
}
```

Comment: I am still getting "active" for every row in the column

Comment: @ConfusedCoder please restart R and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
status <- c("active", "idle")
beaver2$activ <- status[beaver2$activ+1]
```